# ruby key not found using Modulo

Tags: ruby, tiny-tds

I am trying to use the string's modulo function `%` to take a hash and inject it's values into the appropriate places inside of a string but I always receive `key{x} not found (KeyError)` even though I can confirm that the key is there. What am I doing wrong?

```
s = "Invalid: %{totalInvalid} , OutofThreshold: %{totalOutOfThreshold} "
puts row.fetch ('totalInvalid') #<-Just checking to make sure the key is in there
ext = s % row
```

I get this output:

```
0 #<- Key does seem to be in there, returns correct value
in `%': key{totalInvalid} not found (KeyError)
```

The hash is being provided from tiny tds (hitting an SQL server) and when puts is used on it:

```
{"environment"=>"prd       ", "locale"=>"uk        ", "totalProducts"=>666, "to
talOutOfThreshold"=>0, "totalInvalid"=>0, "epochtime"=>1444444444, "thresholdPro
ductIds"=>"", "invalidProductIds"=>""}
```

Comment: Sorry, row is the second output / the hash at the bottom of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In here, the hash keys should be symbols instead of strings, so try the following:

```
to_inject = row.each_with_object({}) { |(key, value), h| h[key.to_sym] = value  }
s = "Invalid: %{totalInvalid} , OutofThreshold: %{totalOutOfThreshold} "
ext = s % to_inject
```

This should help!

Comment: Thanks, If I could +1 here I would.

Comment: If that solves your problem it might be worth making the answer as correct, so in case someone is looking for solution of problem similar to yours, he can find this will help! Cheers!