# Is there a Ruby equivalent of the Java MessageFormat?

Tags: ruby, messageformat

I have a string of the format:

`Hello {0}, today is {1} and the time is {2}. Will you be eating {3}?`

Given an array `["sir", "Monday", "12:00", "tacos"]`, this string should be formatted to:

`Hello sir, today is Monday and the time is 12:00. Will you be eating tacos?`

Does Ruby have some sort of built in method to do this? Or is there a gem? Or do I have to just replace the strings?

Edit: I do want to add that I am not allowed to edit these strings. Therefore sprintf-like solutions would not work.

Answer (score 5):

With [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf):

```
sprintf("Hello %s, today is %s and the time is %s. Will you be eating %s?", *["sir", "Monday", "12:00", "tacos"])
```

or

```
"Hello %s, today is %s and the time is %s. Will you be eating %s?" % ["sir", "Monday", "12:00", "tacos"]
```

Comment: You can target specific arguments using `%1$s`, `%2$s`, `%3$s` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
message = "Hello %{tile}, today is %{day_name} and the time is %{time}. Will you be eating %{food}?"

p message % { title: "sir", day_name: "Monday", time: "12:00", food: "tacos" }
```

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28965384/4381282)!

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
 "Hello %s, today is %s and the time is %s. Will you be eating %s?" % ["sir", "Monday", "12:00", "tacos"]
# => "Hello sir, today is Monday and the time is 12:00. Will you be eating tacos?"
```

Answer (score 0):

I [made one](https://rubygems.org/gems/message_format), but as Ruby is not my strongest suit, any improvements would be much appreciated. The source is on [github](https://github.com/format-message/message-format-rb).